# Building and returning HTTP request in a function to use in from operator

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I've made this function below. The idea is that instead of having multiple `http.get` or `http.post` requests everywhere, i've placed it inside a function so I can just call that function and pass in the appropriate parameters.

```
async buildHTTPRequest(type: string, params: any = ''): Promise<any> {
    this.globalsService.isBlank(this.apiURL).then(async isBlank => {
      if (!isBlank) {
        if (type === 'GET') {
          return await this.http.get(this.apiURL + this.pageUrl + params, {}, this.globalsService.httpHeaders);
        } else if (type === 'POST') {
          return await this.http.post(this.apiURL + this.pageUrl, params, this.globalsService.httpHeaders);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Let's say I have a function called `getData()` that has this code:

```
from(this.buildHTTPRequest('GET'))
  .pipe(finalize(() => { }))
  .subscribe(response => {

  }, err => { this.onError(err); });
```

However, I think `this.buildHTTPRequest('GET')` is returning undefined everytime and i'm not sure why. Any way I can this to work or improve it?

Answer (score 0):

**A possible solution**

If you are looking for a suggestion on how to simplify your code then create an API service with the needed configuration. Take advantage of the observables that come out of the box instead of working with promises.

```
class ApiService {


    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    }

    public get(/* config and whatever have you */) {
        return this.http.get(/* config and whatever have you */);
    }

    public post(/* config and whatever have you */) {
        return this.http.post(/* config and whatever have you */);
    }

}
```

Then call it in another service or anywhere for that matter:

```
this.apiService.get(/* whatever you want to pass in */)
```

As far as avoiding multiple `get()` and `post()` calls. I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind that. It's a web application that most likely needs data from an external source. As long as you can encapsulate redundant configuration into a single service, you can reuse it anytime you need to get data from your server.

**About word about async / await**

The `await` keyword is designed to work with promises. `this.http.get()` returns an observable, so if you must have a promise, you'll have to call `this.http.get().toPromise()` inorder for `await` to work properly.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient